# Excel to Word - Formatted with Titles, Heading 1, via ActiveX Check Box

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Please see attached image.

I showed a simplified version of what my sheet will be doing. But I will have nearly 100 check boxes, with 100 different topics.

My issue is I want to ONLY show content on the Word Doc when the associated checkbox is "true" on the excel sheet. It must also have 'Heading 1' formatting, and hyperlinks. What is my best path forward?

1. Have all the content prepopulated in the Word Doc, and have a macro that deletes content that isn't checked in the excel doc?
2. Start with a blank Word Doc, and populate only content that is checked in Excel.

I have successfully created a way to populate data from excel to word using bookmarks, but not sure how to remove content I don't need.

Thanks so much for your time!

excel to word example

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question if you would like help with it. If you are expecting someone here to just write it all for you then I suggest you re-read the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/excel-to-word-using-activex-check-boxes-with-formatted-text.43089/. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Multiple other cross-posts also...